# get total no data under for every row

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a this database where id is unique for every user.
let me explain in detail:

```
    id 3989 was refered by 1001
and id 3992 was refered by 3989
```

according to requirement.

Now, 1001 have total two member while 3989 have 1

This can go upto infinity.

Now how do i get all those list who have more than 10 refer.

column name prefix contains parent node for every child.

id 3991 have both 1001 and 3989.

as for 3993 it have all 1001, 3989 and 3991 as well.

if you didn't understand question please fell free to ask.
THANK-YOU

[image]

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: i want to find out total no of refer made by each user. it can be either direct refer or indirect refer. or better all those member who made more than 10 sub member.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
Select count(T1.id) From table T1, table T2 Where T1.id=T2.refered_by Group by T1.refered_by`
```

Comment: in my case these all data is in same table. so what should i do for table T2 ??

Comment: i tried to run but following error occured:

Select count(id) From table member_name, table member_name Where member_name.id=member_name.refered_by Group by refered_by
 LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table member_name, table member_name Where member_name.id=member_name.refered_by' at line 1

Comment: it is the same table T1 and T2 just to make the join tablename tablename T1 and T2 for MySQL makes the difference

Comment: in the From of your mysql query you can not put a table twice if you only reference with different references as in your case table

Comment: i tried running but this time i got different error:

#1052 - Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous 
my table name is member_name:

my query was: Select count(id) From member_name T1, member_name T2 Where T1.id=T2.refered_by Group by T1.refered_by


can you please provide working code i am just the beginner

Comment: you must reference each assigned if T1 or T2 for id adds T1.id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105553/discussion-between-bhrached-and-whoknows).